# std::sort of polymorphic types not sorting as expected

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overloading

I have taken sample code from ch9 Open Closed Principle in Agile Software Development, as below, which is supposed to sort shapes by precedence in the order given by the table typeOrderTable in the code below. Well, I did have to add a main and test code but pretty much copied the book code.  But the output shows it is not sorting as per the table.  And if I try to debug the code, the code path does not enter the Shape::Precedes function.

How can I fix this?

Code:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Shape {
public:
    virtual void Draw() const = 0;
    bool Precedes(const Shape& s) const;
    bool operator<(const Shape& s) const {
        return Precedes(s);
    }

private:
    static const char* typeOrderTable[];
};

bool Shape::Precedes(const Shape& s) const {
    const char* thisType = typeid(*this).name();
    const char* argType = typeid(s).name();

    bool done{ false };
    int thisOrd{ -1 };
    int argOrd{ -1 };
    for (int i = 0; !done; ++i) {
        const char* tableEntry = typeOrderTable[i];
        if (tableEntry != 0) {
            if (strcmp(tableEntry, thisType) == 0)
                thisOrd = i;
            if (strcmp(tableEntry, argType) == 0)
                argOrd = i;
            if (argOrd >= 0 && thisOrd >= 0)
                done = true;
        }
        else done = true;
    }
    return thisOrd < argOrd;
}


class Square : public Shape {
public:
    virtual void Draw() const {
        cout << "square\n";
    }
};

class Circle : public Shape {
public:
    virtual void Draw() const {
        cout << "circle\n";
    }
};

class Rectangle : public Shape {
public:
    virtual void Draw() const {
        std::cout << "rectangle\n";
    }
};

const char* Shape::typeOrderTable[] = {
    typeid(Circle).name(),
    typeid(Rectangle).name(),
    typeid(Square).name(),
    0
};

void DrawAllShapes(vector<Shape*> shapes) {
    vector<Shape*> orderedList = shapes;
    sort(orderedList.begin(), orderedList.end());

    for (auto shape : orderedList) {
        shape->Draw();
    }
}

int main() {
    Shape* circle = new Circle();
    Shape* square = new Square();
    Shape* rectangle = new Rectangle();
    Shape* rectangle2 = new Rectangle();

    vector<Shape*> shapes{ rectangle, square, circle, rectangle2 };
    DrawAllShapes(shapes);
    /* should print:
    circle
    rectangle
    rectangle
    square

    but instead prints:
    rectangle
    square
    rectangle
    circle

    ie unsorted - actually it is random in the output
    */
}
```

Comment: Your sort compares the pointer values (i.e., addresses), not the contents pointed to. You need to use a custom comparator in the sort call.

Comment: Side note: since C++11 use of raw pointers and manually mange memory is not recommended. Use `std::unique_ptr` https://godbolt.org/z/Prbhdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your call to std::sort(...) to use a comparator. The way you have it, it is pointers to shapes being sorted not shapes so the `operator<` defined for shapes will not be called, instead the numeric values of the pointers will be compared.

One way to fix this is to sort like this

```
sort(orderedList.begin(), orderedList.end(),
    [](Shape* s1, Shape* s2) { return s1->Precedes(*s2); }
);
```

providing a lambda taking `Shape*`'s to do the actual comparing.